# How to get value from two models in a single view

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

```
I have to return values from two modelandview methods to a single jsp `mySoftwarelist.jsp` where i have two tables. Here i have two seperate methods for returning array list 

    ModelAndView getLegacySuiteList()
    ModelAndView getSuiteList()

i returned the arraylist `mySoftwareList`,`mySoftwareLegacyList` to the same view `swl_mySoftwareList` as

public ModelAndView getSuiteList(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{
ArrayList mySoftwareList = new ArrayList();    
 try{
MySoftwareListHelper mySoftwareListHelper = new MySoftwareListHelper();
userEmailAddr =user.getEmailaddress();      
mySoftwareList = mySoftwareListHelper.getSuites(userEmailAddr);

}
catch(Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
ModelAndView mnv = new ModelAndView("swl_mySoftwareList","mySoftwareList",mySoftwareList);
return mnv;

}

public ModelAndView getLegacySuiteList(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{       
ArrayList mySoftwareLegacyList = new ArrayList();       
try{
MySoftwareListHelper mySoftwareListHelper = new MySoftwareListHelper();
userEmailAddr =user.getEmailaddress();
mySoftwareLegacyList = mySoftwareListHelper.getLegacySuites(userEmailAddr);
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

ModelAndView mnv = new ModelAndView("swl_mySoftwareList","mySoftwareLegacyList",mySoftwareLegacyList);
return mnv;

}

but its returning only the model `mySoftwareList`.
I want data from both the arraylist to be used on same jsp.

Comment: Please show us the actual methods, not just individual lines of code.

Comment: @skaffman hi i have added the exact method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add both the list separately in the same mnv object before you return to the view.

```
ModelAndView mnv = new ModelAndView("swl_mySoftwareList","mySoftwareList",mySoftwareList); 
mnv.addObject("mySoftwareLegacyList",mySoftwareLegacyList);

return mnv;
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: thanks @Japan Trivedi... but for me objects were in different methods

Comment: Hi please refer the above edited format where i have added methods.

Comment: Ok now I got what your problem is.

Since you are retrning a new ModelAndView object every time, the previously added object will not be included in newly created mnv object in another request. So you need to have a common map for the whole controller and add the required object everytime.

Comment: Thnkxs i am a newbie i dont know how add a common map can please give me an example

Comment: But what if you include both the list in both methods like I say. Won't that work for you?? I think it should.

Comment: One more thing you can do is add them in the session.

Comment: Trived ya this is working fine thanks, but could you please help me how can add a model map for the above.

Comment: You don't need a model map if you are adding the object directly in your mnv. Like I have explained in the answer. Please refer that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice is to use DTO object which get the required properties from both entities and then pass that DTO object in to the view.